# Can I sum up different logs in a query widget for datadog dashboard?

Tags: logging, metrics, datadog

I have a bunch of logs that are supposed to be summed up into a value, that I would like to monitor. I tried sum function in the query widget and in table widget but nether seems to work with logs and not metrics. Anyone did something similar? Thanks